# I can not select a Database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to insert form data into a table which was created in phpMyAdmin.

```
<?php
    $DisplayForm = True;
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','user','password');
        if(!$con) {
            die('Nicht mit dem Server verbunden' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysqli_select_db($con,"ergebnisse");
        if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'ergebnisse')) {
            echo 'Datenbase nicht ausgewählt. <br/>';
        }
        $sql = "INSERT * INTO 'ergebnisse' ('Ergebnis') VALUES ('$_POST[eingabe]')";
        if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
            echo 'Nicht eingefügt. <br/>';
        }
        $DisplayForm = False;
        echo 'Danke für deine Teilnahme!';
    }
    if ($DisplayForm) {
?>
    <form action="Umfrage.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="eingabe">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Absenden">
    </form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

The code does connect to the server but the following code doesn't work so it doesn't select the database and it doesn't insert the form data.

Comment: First you are using `mysqli` to connect, then you write `mysql_error()`. Change that and see what's gonna happen. Also the user and pass are the right ones?

Comment: that ^ isn't the only thing failing. Incorrect identifier qualifiers used.

Comment: Also remove the `*` from the `INSERT` query.

Comment: Please sanitize your database input to avoid sql injection attacks.  Parametrized queries are typically the preferred way of doing it.

Comment: I have changed it but still nothing happens.